# how to display image from database using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I have a problem with displaying an image using jquery. The image is retrieved from the database, and i want to display it using jquery. below is my codes

#### index.php

```php
<?php 
require_once("db.php");

if(isset($_POST['input'])):

$id = $_POST['id'];

    $selectImage = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT product_image FROM products WHERE id = ? ");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($selectImage, "i",$id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($selectImage);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($selectImage,$image);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectImage);

    if($image):
      echo $image;

    else:
       echo "no image to display";
    endif;

endif;
?>
```

#### ajax.php

```javascript
function imgViews(){
    $(".imageView").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
                url: 'class/display_image.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {input: 'input',
                       id:id
                   },
                success:function(data){
                 ****display image*****
                },
                dataType: "text"
        });
    });
}
imgViews();
```

#### displayHere.html

```html
<div id="imageContainer>
    <img src="img/...."> 
</div>
```

Comment: just send entire image tag with src from server, and .html() to the div.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, please share your answer as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @dmh given answers are also do the same thing so OP can use it.

Comment: Sorry @DevsiOdedra, I couldn't see that when I added my comment (from triage).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
success:function(data){
   $('#imageContainer').html('<img src="'+data+'"/>');
},
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will help you

$("#imageContainer img").attr("src", data);

Answer (score 0):

**index.php**

```
<?php 
require_once("db.php");
if(isset($_POST['input'])):
$id = $_POST['id'];
$selectImage = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT product_image FROM products WHERE id = ? 
");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($selectImage, "i",$id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($selectImage);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($selectImage,$image);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($selectImage);

if($image):?>
<div id="img_id"><?php echo $image; ?></div> 
<?php  
else: ?>
<div id="img_id"></div>
<?php 
endif;
endif;
?>
```

**ajax.php**

```
function imgViews(){
    $(".imageView").click(function(){
        var id = $('img_id').text().trim();

        if(id != ""){
             $.ajax({
                    url: 'class/display_image.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {input: 'input',
                           id:id
                       },
                    success:function(data){
                     $('#imageContainer').html('<img src="'+data+'"/>');
                    },
                    dataType: "text"
            });
        }
    });
  }
  imgViews();
```

Comment: So the returned data in your answer will be `<div id="img_id"></div>` then how can you use  `.html('<img src="'+data+'"/>');`

Comment: if your class/display_image.php is index.php then php code will remain same as yours

Comment: @Harrybaldaniya thanx for a trick. i modify the codes that made the returned data to be `<img src='img/<?php echo $image;?>'>`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('#pic').html('"<img src="'+ picURL + data +'"/>');
```